# In Shell, dot in string cause -eq operation fail with error: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "\.test")

Tags: shell

This works fine:

```
if [[ "test" -eq "test" ]]
then
    echo "test compare"
fi
```

But it fails if I add a dot

```
if [[ ".test" -eq ".test" ]]
then
    echo "test compare"
fi
```

syntax error: operand expected (error token is ".test")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`-eq` operator is used to compare **integers**](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions), no strings.

You need to use `=` or `==` to compare strings properly:

```
if [[ '.test' = '.test' ]]
then
    echo "test compare"
fi
```